# postman websites links not working using postman in codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, paypal, codeigniter-3, postman

I am trying to make payments using paypal sandbox account in postman.The pages are displaying very well but on clicking the continue button, its not working. I have also tried facebook and gmail sites, the pages are displaying but on submitting the login credentials nothing happens.

Comment: any idea will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that its impossible to make payments inside the postman. I just created UI outside the API and it worked for me.